# Python Keras weighted accuracy metric is much different than regular accuracy metric

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics, weighted

I am training a Transformer model for Time Series Classification. To check the results, I am using a Baseline model which uses the previous target as the next prediction. I am using a data generator to handle the data. The dataset is imbalanced so I am using sample_weights to deal with this, so the data generator outputs 3 variables: inputs, labels, sample_weights.

I have tried setting the sample_weights to all 1's in order to test that things are working well. The baseline model produces identical results with weighted accuracy and regular accuracy, which is expected. However for the Transformer, I am seeing completely different values for the weighted accuracy and regular accuracy, even though the sample_weights are all 1's. Since the sample weights are all 1's I would expect the weighted accuracy to be the same as the regular accuracy, Why are these different?

It seems like the regular metric is normalized to 1, while the weighted metric is normalized to 100, but why would these be different in this case?

Code:
Function from data generator class to get sample weights

```
def get_sample_weights(self, inputs, labels):
        ''' Obtains sample weights for any number of classes.
            NOTE: sample_weights pertain a weighting to each label
            '''

        # get initial sample weights
        sample_weights = tf.ones_like(labels, dtype=tf.float64)
        
        # get classes and counts for each one
        class_counts = np.bincount(self.train_df.price_change)
        total = class_counts.sum()
        n_classes = len(class_counts)

        weights = tf.constant([1, 1, 1], dtype=tf.float64)
        for idx, count in enumerate(class_counts):
            # compute weight
            # weight = total / (n_classes*count)
            weight = weights[idx]

            # update weight value 
            sample_weights = tf.where(tf.equal(labels, float(idx)), 
                                      weight, 
                                      sample_weights)
        
        return inputs, labels, sample_weights
```

get baseline results

```
baseline = Baseline(label_index=single_gen.column_indices['price_change'])

baseline.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                 metrics=['accuracy'],
                 weighted_metrics=['accuracy'])

train_metrics = baseline.evaluate(single_gen.train))
val_metrics = baseline.evaluate(single_gen.valid))
```

[image]

Get results with Transformer

```
transformer_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4),
                  metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'],
                  weighted_metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

history = transformer_model.fit(aapl_gen.train, 
                                epochs=2,
                                validation_data=aapl_gen.valid)


train_metrics = transformer_model.evaluate(data_gen.train)
val_metrics = transformer_model.evaluate(data_gen.valid)
```

[image]

Comment: Using, ```metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]``` provides expected results, where weighted and regular accuracies are equal.